# Cannot insert data into my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to INSERT data into my database but even the Insert Values are picked up correctly the query is not executed and values not inserted, I have tried the same query using SQL console in PHPmyAdmin and the INSERT worked perfect.

I checked my connection details and they are correct, Have no Idea what might be the reason please have a look at my code....

insert.php:

```
  if($_POST['action'] == 'Save') {

     class tempManagment
     {
        public function con() {
           require_once('connect.php');
           $DB = new dbConnect();

           return $DB->connect();
        }

        public function saveTemplate($user, $name, $date, $template, $used) {

           $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE ott_email='$user'";
           $query = mysqli_query($this->con(), $sql);
           $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

           var_dump($query);
           echo "<br />";

           if($count == 1) {

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                 $id = $row['user_id'];

                 $save = "INSERT INTO tbl_saved_template (user_id, temp_name, save_date, temp_html, temp_used) VALUES ('$id','$name','$date','$template','$used')";
                 $insert = mysqli_query($this->con(), $save);

                 var_dump($save);
                 echo "<br />";
                 var_dump($insert);

              }
           }
        }
     }

     $save = new tempManagment();
     $save->saveTemplate($_SESSION['user'], $email['subject'], date('Y-m-d'), $email['HTML'], 1);
  }
```

**var_dump output**

```
var_dump($query) = object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

var_dump($save) = string(20877) "INSERT INTO tbl_saved_template (user_id, temp_name, save_date, temp_html, temp_used) VALUES ('77','asdasdasd','2014-05-13','SOME HTML HERE','1'"

var_dump($insert) = bool(false)
```

Looking at these I understand that the query is not executed but I cannot understand why

Also I would like to mention that the `tbl_saved_template->user_id` is a foreign key to `tbl_user` table and `tbl_saved_template` primate key is `AI` `savedtemp_id`

Comment: Can you provide dump for tbl_saved_template?

Comment: Use `mysqli_error()` after the insert command to view any errors.  It is likely that a foreign key constraint is causing an error.

Comment: you're missing `)` after `values`, at least in var_dump output

Comment: i will check the mysqli error and let u know the result

Comment: @user3065962 Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the PHP file to print the error.

Comment: @user3065962 How `'$id'` is foreign key and seems to be an `INT`, you can remove the quotes.

Comment: Hey guys I have tired all the above non helped unfortinally, But I have removed the HTML contend value and replaced it with a sample string and it works, so there is some problem with the Mysql to INSERT html code into tables.....?

Comment: can you show you html code ?

Comment: I fixed it i just wrapped my html code with mysqli_real_escape_string, and works brilliant thank you guys for your suggestions )